# java beans to display form data using session

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, javabeans

How do I store all the details entered by the user, using Java Beans and use session bean to display the PREVIEW of details entered in the form on the Next Page.
I have already created a servlet using JSP, now I want to use JAVA Beans to display the same form data using session or beans how can I do it?

```js
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById("b1").onmouseover = function() {
    this.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
  }

  document.getElementById("b1").onmouseout = function() {
    this.style.backgroundColor = "#9999ff";
  }
}


function validateForm() {
  var x = document.forms["myform"]["pname"].value;
  if (x == "") {
    alert("Name must be filled out");
    return false;
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="column left" style="background-color:#aaa;">

    <form name="myform" action="display.jsp" method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
      Product Name: <input type="text" name="pname"><br> Quality: <br>
      <input type="radio" id="Excellent" name="quality" value="Excellent">
      <label for="Excellent">Excellent</label><br>
      <input type="radio" id="Very Good" name="quality" value="Very Good">
      <label for="Very Good">Very Good</label><br>
      <input type="radio" id="Good" name="quality" value="Good">
      <label for="Good">Good</label><br>
      <input type="radio" id="Fair" name="quality" value="Fair">
      <label for="Fair">Fair</label><br><br>

      <input type="submit" name="submit" id="b1">
    </form>

  </div>
  <div class="column right" style="background-color:#bbb;">
    <div class="vertical-menu">
      <a href="#">Product Feedback</a>
      <a href="home.html">Home</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

My knowledge in this topic can be considered legacy, as it has been a long time where I had used JSP/Servlets.

However, on that regards, if you have a JSP Form, then you need to submit that form to the backend (Servlet) as an example.

The Servlet will then create an instance of your Java Class, and use the .setters() in order to set the java bean.

You will then store this Java bean in the user session, and have it accessible in the other pages.

http://courses.coreservlets.com/Course-Materials/csajsp2.html

[Get information from JSP(form) to Java Bean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3563387/get-information-from-jspform-to-java-bean)